# Run inline javascript on specific page wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to run a jQuery code only on simple product pages in WooCommerce.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

let qty = document.getElementById('qty');

qty.onblur = function(){
  let val  = this.value; // Current Value
  let step = this.getAttribute('step'); // Get step instead of hard coding it

  let roundDown = (val - (val % step)).toFixed(2);
  let roundUp   = (parseFloat(roundDown) + parseFloat(step)).toFixed(2);

  this.value = roundUp;
}

});
```

How can I achieve this in Javascript code?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. What precisely are you asking?

Comment: you want not to use jQuery ? or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code causes an error, because on the remaining pages there is no element with id "qty", you can add this code to your main js file like this:

```
$(function() {

  if ( $('#qty').length ) {
     let qty = document.getElementById('qty');

     qty.onblur = function(){
       let val  = this.value; // Current Value
       let step = this.getAttribute('step'); // Get step instead of hard coding it

       let roundDown = (val - (val % step)).toFixed(2);
       let roundUp   = (parseFloat(roundDown) + parseFloat(step)).toFixed(2);

       this.value = roundUp;
     }
  }

});
```

Or you can add this code to footer.php before the closing  tag, adding the output condition:

```
<?php is_singular( 'products' ) :?> <!--change this to your need - https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags -->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

let qty = document.getElementById('qty');

qty.onblur = function(){
  let val  = this.value; // Current Value
  let step = this.getAttribute('step'); // Get step instead of hard coding it

  let roundDown = (val - (val % step)).toFixed(2);
  let roundUp   = (parseFloat(roundDown) + parseFloat(step)).toFixed(2);

  this.value = roundUp;
}

});
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Best way you can add Javascript to WordPress

1. Save your above code to a file, named **only-page.js** and upload to your theme folder.
2. Add below code to your theme's functions.php file:

   ```
   function f50668438_enqueue_script() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'only-page-custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/only-page.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
   }

   if( is_page(2) ){ // page ID or page slug here
       add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'f50668438_enqueue_script' );
   }
   ```
3. Done